# select grandparent in css

Tags: css, parent-child

i have an html code like this

```
<div class="main-container">
   <div class="main">
     <div class="col-main">
        <div class="category-products">
           <div class="toolbar"> </div>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

i've tried to change the **main-container** background if it has toolbar descendant, ive tried like this :

```
 .main-container > .main .col-main .category-products .toolbar{
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  padding-top: 0;
}

.main-container >  .toolbar{
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

but nothing works

Comment: This is way beyond css..this is in fact more of a javascript conditional testing and then apply a css style. css rules moves from top to bottom. it can't check for html objects and then travel back up the DOM to style

Comment: You need to use Jquery for this . Not possible with  css only. Are you open to use jquery?

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```css
.main-container[data-toolbaar="yes"] {
   background-color:#999;
```

```html
<div class="main-container" data-toolbaar="yes">
   <div class="main">
     <div class="col-main">
        <div class="category-products">
           <div class="toolbar"> HELLO</div>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Description**

You can pass a custom  attribute `data-toolbar="yes"` and target it with css properties and change the target `class` or `id` properties.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't traverse backwards with css. So you have to resort to javascript or find some other way.

IF however .main-container didn't have any children (or any other content) you could style it like this:

```css
.main-container {
  height: 200px;
  background: tomato;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.main-container:not(:empty){
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container" data-toolbaar="yes">
   <div class="main">
     <div class="col-main">
        <div class="category-products">
           <div class="toolbar"> HELLO</div>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>

<!-- EMPTY -->
<div class="main-container" data-toolbaar="yes"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.main-container{
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
   <div class="main">
     <div class="col-main">
        <div class="category-products">
           <div class="toolbar">CSS set background color</div>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```